# lsnrctl - nothing happens Oracle 11gr2 + Ubuntu 14

Tags: linux, oracle, oracle11g, listener, ubuntu-14.04

I installed Oracle 11gR2 in Ubuntu 14, create listener and a net service. When I try to run **lsnrctl stat** or **lsnrctl start** nothing happens. It is expected something like that

> LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 03-JUL-2015
>   08:33:45
>
> Copyright (c) 1991, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
>
> Welcome to LSNRCTL, type "help" for information.

But absolutely nothing happens just jump to another terminal line like press Enter.

If i try to run **sqlplus /  as sysdba** it connect fine but If i try to connect using anohter user I receive

> ORA-12541: TNS:no listener

Can someone help me?

Comment: Do you have an alias set for `lsnrctl`? What does `which lsnrctl` or `whence -v lsnrctl` show?

Comment: Update your question with output of #netstat -tulpn | grep :1521 and #echo $TNS_ADMIN